# GPS Middleware server - save position and send data to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, gps

I have a GPS device for my car and I would use gps tracker service but server which I choose doesn't support iframe plugins to share position on my website.
My idea is create something middleware server. First I get data from device in my server, save position and send data to next server.
I found nodejs server (https://www.pincer.io/npm/libraries/tracker-stream) but I don't sure if i doing it good.

```
var net = require('net');
var Tk104Stream = require('tracker-stream').Tk104Stream;
var Tk104Reply = require('tracker-stream').Tk104Reply;
var server = new net.Socket();

net.createServer(function(client) {
    server.connect(#port#, #ip#, function() {
    console.log('Connected with GPS Server');
      client.pipe(new Tk104Stream()).on('data', function(data) {
        var x = server.write(data);
        console.log('status: ', x);
      }).pipe(new Tk104Reply()).pipe(client);
  });
}).listen(3003);
```

Status respond mi: true, but on server service doesn't see my data.

Thanks for any answers :)

Comment: have you managed to track the gps device with node js ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I found a solution :)

https://gonzalo123.com/2012/09/17/building-a-simple-tcp-proxy-server-with-node-js/

Maybe question and answer help :)
So I do not delete the thread